# How can I avoid super constructor with Mockito or PowerMock?

Tags: java, android, mockito, powermock

My class extends from View and I need to test the init method.
I can't create an empty constructor nor call the method directly because of the class initialization. How can I skip this super?

```
public GifView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }
```

Comment: mock the superclass?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to skip the call to `suoer()` completely? http://blog.jdriven.com/2013/05/mock-superclass-method-with-mockito/

Comment: I saw that link before, and if I didn't read wrong, it works just for methods not constructors.

Comment: I found this link, but I'm getting Stub troubles: http://www.gitshah.com/2010/06/how-to-supress-methods-and-constructors.html